# Built a react app, but I'm storing everything in localstorage (just for testing). I want to hook up my data with my mongodb. How do I go about this?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs

I've built a small react app where you can make new "posts" (kind of like pinterest pins).  Each post has a title, message, image.  Then, you can like posts, and the likes that each post has are stored.

I have two main states - posts{} and likes{} - that I would like to store and call from mongo.  Right now, I'm storing my states in local storage.. which is not 'real world like'

Can someone point me into the right direction?  Is this also a good time to start understanding flux?  How I can get my mongo API plugged in?

Please help

Comment: I would split into two questions: 1) how to do db/network requests from React (this is extensively covered in tutorials and other SO questions) and 2) how can a webpage/app get information from MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [meteor](http://www.meteor.com). It looks like the perfect tool for your app.